# Update many2one domain filter from button function [odoo12]

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12, odoo-domain

I am trying to update the domain filter for a many2one field from button click, the function runs, but I do not see any change on the UI, here is the class I am using:

```
class ProjectTask(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'project.task'

    my_users = fields.Many2one('res.users', string="My Users", readonly=False)

    def filterUsers(self):
        domain = ...mydomainTogetUsers
        filtered_users = self.env['res.users'].search(domain).mapped('id')
        return {'domain': {'my_users ': [('id', 'in', filtered_users)]}}
```

I have the following object button on view to execute function:

```
<button name="filterUsers" string="Filter Users" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
```

Function gets executed but many2one field remains the same.

Is there any way to update the field list after calling the function?

Comment: show your many2one field xml.

Comment: visit this: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/odoo10-dynamic-domain-118053

Comment: You can set `my_users` field to be computed.

Comment: This is my many2one field `<field name="my_users" />`, since I am trying to update domain from model I did not add domain on view

Answer (score 0):

try to change in your search method like following :

```
def filterUsers(self):
    domain = ...mydomainTogetUsers
    filtered_users = self.env['res.users'].search(my_users).mapped('id')
    #or this line:
    filtered_users = self.env['res.users'].mapped(my_users).mapped('id')
    return {'domain': {'my_users ': [('id', 'in', filtered_users)]}}
```